# PHP - Line hight light if word occurs fix

Tags: php

Hello I have a little problem

This is my current code

```
<?php
$str = trim($_POST['email']);
$str = nl2br($str); // insert <br /> before \n 


$str = preg_replace($whitelistPregReplace, '<span style="color:blue">$1$2$3</span>', $str);

echo $str;
?>
```

The problem is it hightlight the whole line if "1bird.one" occurs. I want hightlight whole line  only if "bird.one" occurs, not fdsfsdfsdbird.onefdsfsd ocurs

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use word boundaries (`\b`) to indicate the string should not be right next to other 'word' characters:

```
~(.*)\b(bird\.one)\b(.*)~im
```

This will match `efgerv bird.one evwerg`, but fail on `rgbre 1bird.one erfrwf`.

https://regex101.com/r/riUhdD/1

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
    $str = 'bird.one';
    $whitelist = [
        'bird.one',
        'bird.two'
    ];
    for($i = 0; $i < count($whitelist);$i++){
       if (strcmp($whitelist[$i], $str) == 0) { 
              /** add the span to highlight */ 
           echo "<span style='color:blue'>{$str}</span><br>";
       } else {
            /** other text to echo */
        }
    }
?>
```

Will only echo and highligh bird.one. easily adaptable

Comment: Yeah, but you use for loop instead of foreach, also he want whole text with highlight part, anyway i will save this solution, thank u !

Comment: What's the difference between loop and foreach in a non associative array? He can still display everything else lol. just needs an else statement